# Parse Domain From String Text

Tags: php, parsing

I would like to search through the strings I have and pull out the domain name that may end with .com .net etc...

```
$string = "Just head over to nba.com";
$string = "visit cnn.net";
```

Please help me extract the domain name above into a variable.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried and what issues did you encounter with those solutions?

Comment: Is domain always the last item on the string or it may appear at different positions ?

Comment: Googling `php parse url from string` turns up many useful solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (preg_match_all('/\w+\.(com|net)/', $text, $matches)){
   print_r($matches);
}
```

The first match will be:

```
echo $matches[0][0];
```